# How to challenge Windows Azure Active Directory authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

We have a SPA with angularjs 1.6 and asp.net web API. We use Microsoft Account Authentication in OWIN middleware.

**In Startup.Auth.cs**

```
MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions microsoftAccountAuthenticationOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Caption = "Connection with your Microsoft account",
    ClientId = microsoftAccountAuthenticationConfigurationElement.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = microsoftAccountAuthenticationConfigurationElement.ClientSecret,
};
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftAccountAuthenticationOptions);
```

**Our controller method to challenge the authentication**

```
[Route("ExternalLogin")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult ExternalLogin(string authenticationType, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(new List<AuthenticationHeaderValue>(), this)
    {
        RedirectUri = this.Url.Route("ExternalLoginCallback", new { returnUrl }),
        AuthenticationType = authenticationType
    };
}
```

**And the ChallengeResult class**

```
internal class ChallengeResult : UnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(IEnumerable<AuthenticationHeaderValue> challenges, ApiController controller):base(challenges, controller)
    { }

    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = this.RedirectUri }, this.AuthenticationType);
        return base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.

Now we want add an Office365 authentication. So we use Windows Azure Active Directory authentication:

```
WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Tenant = windowsAzureActiveDirectoryAuthenticationConfigurationElement.Tenant,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = windowsAzureActiveDirectoryAuthenticationConfigurationElement.Audience
    }
};
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions);
```

And we reuse `ExternalLogin` api to challenge the authentication.
In this case the client receive a unauthorized result 401 instead of the redirect 302.

**My question :** Why the authentication challenge doesn't tranform the unauthorized result in redirect result on https://login.microsoftonline.com/ ?

**Note :** If use ADAl.js on client side to challenge the authentication then the redirection works. But I don't wish use the adal.js library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a SPA + API, the API should do Bearer token authentication as you have configured now.

But the authentication redirect should start from the SPA using ADAL.JS etc.
An API should not do 302 redirects for authentication.
If the caller is a program running on a server, what are they supposed to do?
That's why it returns a 401, because authentication failed.

Comment: Ahh you have a SPA + API. Should probably have read the question a bit more carefully. You need to use bearer as you use now. But your SPA needs to do the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So another question : why the redirection works whith the extension `UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication` and is there a way to not use ADAL.js

Comment: Because that's interactive authentication, same as OpenId Connect. But an API isn't really supposed to use interactive authentication. Typically the request is already authenticated, and if not, return 401.

Comment: What is the problem with ADAL.JS? :)

Comment: well, I have a loop problem like described in the [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs) but after 4 days   of research and test I always unable to correct the problem...

Comment: Well, you could look at other libraries (like HelloJS), but I am not sure if they support Azure AD's v1 endpoint since it is not fully standards-compliant (the resource parameter). It might be best if you post another question about that problem. Add the code in the SPA handling the authentication and I'll take it a look at it too.